# How to set input field value of a website using asp.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to auto assign an input text field  of this website :http://www.wine-searcher.com/wine-valuation-f.lml

I used to  do it with  webBrowser in  windows form application with document.getElementByID("").InnerText but I don't have any idea to emulate that in asp.net
please any  suggestions( ?)

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to clarify your question. As it currently reads, Javascript is Javascript - ASP.Net is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you use asp.net 2.0 you can set that ddl to have  runat="server", and then set value in C#.

If you want to change default values of that control in javascript I prefer to use jQuery

```
 $("document").ready(function () {    //this will start on page ready
    var objs = $(".valftltsml");     //this will find all ctrl with class valftltsml

    jQuery.each(objs, function () {      //this will iterate over all ctrl
        $("#" + this.id).TODO_SOMETHING; //this will do something
    });
});
```